# Should I use DMA or tensile and compressive testing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, materials

I have some polymer based samples (the exact composition is proprietary) that were additively manufactured, however the sample amount is severely limited so I'm limited on the amount of material testing that I can do. Therefore, would anyone recommend DMA (Dynamic Mechanical Analysis) over standard mechanical testing and why? Also, I likely don't have enough material to test all 3 orientations (x,y, and z).

Comment: What are you testing for?